# XPath select until next tag

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, xpath-1.0

I'm scraping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadsden,_Alabama and I want to grab the "Geography and climate" paragraph and all the `text()` elements until the next `h2` tag occurs (which is "Demographics").

I don't want to grab the table in here.

the XPath code I've tried so far is `//span[@id='Geography_and_climate']/following::p`which selects everything until the page ends.

I've tried answers' code of similar problems on StackOverflow but nothing works for me, maybe I'm not an expert to understand their code.

Comment: you may use loop to get `next` element and check if it is already `h2` or not.

Comment: @furas I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I was thinking about loop with `item = item.findNextSibling()` until `item.name == 'h2'` but it is code in `BeautifulSoup` - and if you use `scrapy` then it is not so useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath to select all paragraphs *after Geography&Climate and before Demographics*

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][span[@id='Geography_and_climate']]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. But I still don't get how it worked.

Can you explain me a little?

Comment: @Haseeb , this is shorter version of `//p[preceding-sibling::h2[position()=1 and span[@id='Geography_and_climate']]]` which means *return all paragraphs if its first preceding header has child span with `@id="Geography_and_climate"`*